# Why would you want to use ContinueWith instead of simply appending your continuation code to the end of the background task?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

The MSDN documentation for [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) has only one code example where one task (`dTask`) runs in the background, followed by (using `ContinueWith`) a second task (`dTask2`). Essence of the sample shown below;

```
Task dTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //... first task code here ...
}); 

Task dTask2 = dTask.ContinueWith( (continuation) =>
{
    //... second task code here ...
});
                 
Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { dTask, dTask2 });
```

My question is simply; What is the advantage of calling the second block of code using `.ContinueWith` instead of simply appending it to the first code block, which already runs in the background and changing the code to something like this?

```
Task dTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{
    //... first task code here ...
    if (!cancelled) //and,or other exception checking wrapping etc
    {
        //... second task code here ...
    }
}); 

Task.Wait(dTask);
```

In the suggested revision, avoiding calling `ContinueWith` altogether, the second block of code still runs in the background, plus there's no context switching for the code to get access to closure's state ... I don't get it? Feeling a bit dumb, I've done some googling, and perhaps just not hit on the correct phrase to search for.

**Update:** After Hans Passant posted the link to more [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) notes. That was helpful, sparked some new things I could 'google' for. *(google, as in verb, with a small 'g', [just in case ChrisF want's to edit my post again and capitalise it. ;-D](http://news.cnet.com/2100-1025_3-6091289.html))* But still didn't bring any clarity, for example, [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397163/continuewith-a-task-on-the-main-thread) gives an example of `ContinueWith` and asks an interesting question, "How exactly is it determined when the callback method will execute?". I may be wrong, but it seems to me that for the most common usages, simply appending the continuation code makes it 100% clear when the code will be "scheduled"(executed). In the case of appending the code, it will execute "immediately" after the line above completes, and in the case of `ContinueWith`, well..."it depends", i.e. you need to know the internals of the Task class libraries and what default settings and schedulers are used. So, that's obviously a massive trade-off of, and all the examples offered up so far don't explain WHY or WHEN you would be prepared to make this trade off? If it is indeed a trade off, and not a misunderstanding of `ContinueWith's` intended usage.

Here's an extract from the SO question I referenced above:

```
// Consider this code:
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Whatever());  
task.ContinueWith(Callback), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
// How exactly is it determined when the callback method will execute?
```

In the spirit of learning and exploring more about `ContinueWith` could the above code safely be written as...?

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{ 
    Whatever();
    Callback();
);
```

...and if not, then perhaps the reason why not might lead us towards answering the question with some clarity, i.e. an example showing that the alternative would have to be written as `x` which would be less readable, less safe, more testable?, less ?? than using `.ContinueWith`.

Of course, if anyone can think of a simple **real life scenario** where `ContinueWith` provides real benefit, then that would be first prize as that would means it would be much easier to remember it correctly.

Comment: Suppose you want to download some data from internet and then display it on a textbox without blocking your UI. `Task{downloadData}.ContinueWith{UpdateUI}` is a good option (of course without *Task.Wait*). (Similar to async/await of c# 5.0)

Comment: Look at the bullets in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: One word: composition.

Comment: I've reluctantly given Hans an upvote, since the MSDN documentation for ContinueWith is so shockingly poor, so the link has some value. I don't however believe that the bullet points provide a simple answer to the question, and my gut (yeah yeah)... my "gut" is telling me that everyone is missing the point and this should be explainable with a simple code example. Checking everyone's suggestions has been a great learning experience for me, so please keep them coming. ;-D

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the most obvious (original) reason to use `ContinueWith` is if the code you're working on only has a `Task`. This situation can be fairly common - one layer of code wants to take the results of another layer of code and do something with it (e.g., display it on a UI). You can't conflate the two task bodies without violating separation of concerns. Of course, these days you should use `async`/`await` instead of `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The main reason for continuations is composition and asynchronous code flows.

Composition has died a bit since "mainstream" OOP started, but as C# adopts more and more functional-programming practices (and features), it's also starting to be much more friendly to composition. Why? It allows you to reason about code easily, *especially* when asynchronicity is involved. Just as importantly, it allows you to very easily abstract away how exactly something is executed, which is again quite crucial when handling asynchronous code.

Let's say you need to download a string from some web service, and use that to download another string based on that data.

In old-school, non-asynchronous (and bad) applications, this can look something like this:

```
public void btnDo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var request = WebRequest.Create(tbxUrl.Text);
  var newUrl = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

  request = WebRequest.Create(newUrl);
  var data = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

  lblData.Text = data;
}
```

(error handling and proper disposal omitted :))

This is all fine and dandy, but it has a bit of a problem in blocking the UI thread, thus making your application unresponsive for the duration of the two requests. Now, the typical solution to this was to use something like `BackgroundWorker` to delegate this work to a background thread, while keeping the UI responsive. Of course, this brings two issues - one, you need to make sure the background thread never accesses any UI (in our case, `tbxUrl` and `lblData`), and two, it's kind of a waste - we're using a thread just to block and wait for an asynchronous operation to complete.

A technically better choice would be to use the asynchronous APIs. However, those are *very* tricky to use - a simplified example might look something like this:

```
void btnDo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var request = WebRequest.Create(tbxUrl.Text);
  request.BeginGetResponse(FirstCallback, request);

  var newUrl = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

  request = WebRequest.Create(newUrl);
  var data = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

  lblData.Text = data;
}

void FirstCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
  var response = ((WebRequest)result.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(result);

  var newUrl = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

  var request = WebRequest.Create(newUrl);
  request.BeginGetResponse(SecondCallback, request);
}

void SecondCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
  var response = ((WebRequest)result.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(result);

  var data = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

  BeginInvoke((Action<object>)UpdateUI, data);
}

void UpdateUI(object data)
{
  lblData.Text = (string)data;
}
```

Oh, wow. Now you can see why everyone just started up a new thread instead of mucking with asynchronous code, eh? And note that this is with *no error-handling* whatsoever. Can you imagine how a proper reliable code must have looked like? It wasn't pretty, and most people just never bothered.

But then the `Task` came with .NET 4.0. Basically, this enabled a whole new way of handling asynchronous operations, heavily inspired by functional programming (if you're interested, `Task` is basically a comonad). Along with an improved compiler, this allowed rewriting the whole code above into something like this:

```
void btnDoAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var request = WebRequest.Create(tbxUrl.Text);

  request
  .GetResponseAsync()
  .ContinueWith
  (
    t => 
      WebRequest.Create(new StreamReader(t.Result.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd())
      .GetResponseAsync(),
    TaskScheduler.Default
  )
  .Unwrap()
  .ContinueWith
  (
    t =>
    {
      lblData.Text = new StreamReader(t.Result.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    },
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
  );
}
```

The cool thing about this is that we basically still have something that looks like synchronous code - we just have to add `ContinueWith(...).Unwrap()` everywhere there's an asynchronous call. Adding error handling is mostly just adding another `ContinueWith` with `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`. And of course, we're chaining tasks which are basically "behaviour as a value". This means that it's very easy to create helper methods to do part of the heavy lifting for you - for example, a helper asynchronous method that handles reading the whole response as a string, asynchronously.

Finally, there's not a lot of use cases for continuations in modern C#, because C# 5 added the `await` keyword, which allows you to go even further in pretending that asynchronous code is as simple as synchronous code. Compare the `await` based code to our original, synchronous example:

```
async void btnDo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var request = WebRequest.Create(tbxUrl.Text);
  var newUrl = new StreamReader((await request.GetResponseAsync()).GetResponseStream())
               .ReadToEnd();

  request = WebRequest.Create(newUrl);
  var data = new StreamReader((await request.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream())
             .ReadToEnd();

  lblData.Text = data;
}
```

The `await` "magically" handles all those asynchronous callbacks for us, leaving us with code that's pretty much exactly the same as the original synchronous code - but without requiring multi-threading or blocking the UI. The coolest part is that you can handle errors in the same way as if the method *was* synchronous - `try`, `finally`, `catch`... they all work the same as if everything was synchronous. It doesn't shield you from *all* the trickiness of asynchronous code (e.g. your UI code becomes re-entrant, similar to if you used `Application.DoEvents`), but it does a pretty good job overall :)

It should be rather obvious that if you're writing code with C# 5+, you'll almost always use `await` rather than `ContinueWith`. Is there still a place for `ContinueWith`? The truth is, not a whole lot. I still use it in some simple helper functions, and it's pretty useful for logging (again, since tasks are easily composable, adding logging to an asynchronous function is just a matter of using a simple helper function).

Comment: So sorry to take so long to reply to your answer, and the effort you put in. Stumbled across your answer today while looking for something else! :) cheers, Alan

Comment: desert and reward seldom keep company. The answer merits more pluses.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the code to the original task should be fine if it fits your need. However, `ContinueWith` gives you a bit more flexibility. If you have a `Task` which calculates a result value, you might have several further tasks which depend on that value as input. `ContinueWith` allows you to register all of them independendly. It also decouples the code which creates the original task from the code which hooks up the dependend tasks.

Looking at your second example, the "second task code" is undividably connected to the "first task code" now - meaning that no other part of your program will be able to use the result of the first task code or even see when it is available, unless you add extra communication outside of the "Task" framework.

Of course you could implement it yourself. But it does save you a bit of effort (e.g. making sure that cancellation and exceptions make the whole setup work as expected).

Comment: Hi Medo42, any chance you could provide a short code example explaining your answer? I still don't get it, if the subsequent tasks need the input from the previous task, then if your second task is simply "appended" it will have access to the full scope of all variables of the first task. Ideally the sample code in MSDN should show a usage of the code that solves a problem that the method was designed to specifically solve. Guess maybe my question should read, "can anyone please show me a better same usage?"

Comment: Even in your short example, the `ContinueWith` already saves you from having to check for cancellation and exceptions - try adding the exception handling as well and see if the second code still looks simpler to you. As for the decoupling, just assume that you don't control the creation of the task. Let's say you are using a library that can download a file from the web, and want to do something as soon as that is done. The function `DownloadAsync` would return a `Task<byte[]>`. You can't just add code to that task, so you have to use `ContinueWith`.

Comment: And in a way, you can think of `Task<TResult>` as an aggressive form of `Lazy<T>`. Placing multiple continuations (with `ContinueWith`) on the same `Task` is like referencing the same `Lazy<T>` value from different pieces of code: if two pieces of code can execute concurrently but require the same value, they can both start when the `Task` calculating the value completes. Could you add example code showing something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You have specific continuation options like running only if the first task failed.
In some cases, especially since `async-await` you don't control the first task, you get it from a framework or just a different part of your application.
Examples:

```
    Task task = DoSomethingAsync();
    task.ContinueWith(_ => DoSomethingLong(), TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning);
    task.ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine(_.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: These examples still sound like a class replacement 4 existing language features? e.g. 'try () {  } catch(){} finally {}' using 'try catch' you don't even need to specify that 1 line of code will execute only if the previous line does not throw an exception. Lets say you had 20 tasks, all of which run in the background, not blocking the UI, then 'try { // ur 20 lines } catch( ..)' is way more elegant and easier to read w/o having 2 know detailed knowledge of 'ContinueWith' implementation. Am looking at "the bullets" Hans Passant referred 2 above, will update shortly, txs everyone.

Comment: They're not a replacement, you can still (and mostly should) do it the old fashioned way. But sometimes ("the bullets" are some examples) you will need continuations. I break that to 2 general areas: 1. You need to configure something different about the task (like the `LongRunning` options). 2. Like i said, you have no control over the first task (that's mostly the case).

Comment: The default task scheduler using LongRunning as the default, therefore the code above code also be written as

Comment: oops, got caught by the SO timer! The default task scheduler uses `TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning` as the default, therefore if the code above can also be written as `Task.Run(_=> { try { DoSomethingAsync(); } catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }   });` then it doesn't answer the question. i.e. apart from the syntactic sugar, there's no 'must use' use case, and I would argue my code expresses the intent clearer; What do you think?

Comment: Without any further clarification I think this answer should be downvoted?  **running only if the first task failed** is not a benefit, as ordinary C# `try catch` provides this already and is cleaner.

Comment: Ah, there's no overload for `Task.Run()` that allows you to specify the TaskContinuationOptions. Hmm, maybe `TaskContinuationOptions` options (e.g. `AttachToParent,DenyChildAttach,LazyCancellation...`) might give us a clue to the real uses cases for `.ContinueWith()` ?

Comment: first of all.. `DoSomethingAsync()` is an `async` method that returns a task. Wrapping it with a `try-catch` would accomplish nothing, you need to `Wait()` or better `await` that task to catch any exceptions. The first option will block a thread and the second will force the calling method (or lambda expresion in your case) to be an `async` one. So if you want to add "catch logic" to a task without turning it to an `async` task you better use ContinueWith.

Comment: Secondly, i don't know where you found out that `TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning` is the default because i can't find it anywhere and it seems wrong to me. It means that the thread pool will create a lot of additional threads and most likely hurt performance (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402(v=vs.110).aspx)).
I used `LongRunning` as an example of `TaskContinuationOptions`. You also have `PreferFairness`, `ExecuteSynchronously`, `HideScheduler` and more...

Comment: The thing is it allows you to use composition as you see fit (according to design, performance and so forth). You probably never "must" use `ContinueWith`, but you always **may**. You can assing many continuations with many different options to the same task or one continutation to many tasks (and both).
You may choose to never use that composition in your own code, but the .Net framework is filled with it and then as i said you don't control the first task.
When you use for example .Net's `Stream.WriteAsync` you get a task which is "hot" and you can't change it.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere! let me digest this and reply shortly.

Comment: **re: LongRunning is the defeault...I can't find it anywhere** Mybad! trying to get through quite a bit of reading based on folks suggestions I believe I mis-read an article. Quite a lot to digest at once. A bit of reading while trying to find where I thought I saw it leads me to concur with you, i.e. the default scheduler in most cases uses the ThreadPool, [and thus LongRunning wouldn't make sense and tasks should be short.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/06/9903475.aspx)

Comment: **re: wrapping in a try catch does nothing.** Not being familiar with async and await I completely missed that DoSomethingAsync() is some code implemented with a specific async pattern. Ok, in that case my example should read  `Task.Run(_=> { try { DoSomethingAsync().Wait(); } catch(Aggregate ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Flatten()); } });` and I believe that most of my question still stands, i.e. I think we're missing the point, or, at least no simple example has yet been given, showing a "typical" use case where one would immediately benefit by using .ContinueWith().

Comment: As i said in a previous comment calling `DoSomethingAsync().Wait()` means you're wasting a thread that waits synchronously instead of doing something useful. It means that your application can do less with its resources and is less scalable. The better option is using `await DoSomethingAsync()` which will wait **a** -synchronously while freeing a thread to do other work. The option though forces you to mark the calling method with `async` which is sometimes unwanted or simply impossible. Then you can use a continuation and enjoy both worlds.

Comment: But i feel you're missing the point. You're using tasks so you could break apart code blocks and run them in parallel/asynchronously/certain flow so you can better use your hardware. When you do that you need to have ways to build your flow and ContinueWith is one way to do that. You can write everything in one task just the same as you **can** write everything in one method, but sometimes there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after some reading and experimenting, it looks like the short very broad answer (for me at least) is: If you don't have access to .NET 4.5 & async and await, and you absolutely need to save every single thread you can, then using ContinueWith can save you one thread (or save you blocking a threadpool thread), and possibly (as shown in my spike test code below) at the cost of quite a bit of testability and readability. In most cases pre .net 4.5 appending the code to the end of the background task is the simplest, but as mentioned that will block a threadpool thread, and if you have access to .net 4.5 and use await and async patterns it won't and is almost always simpler and cleaner. Deeply (or not even very deep) use of nested Continuations (callbacks) result very quickly in code that is tricky to read, test and maintain.

I've created an (as simple as possible) sample winform app (code below) that has three buttons, each button doing the same task three different ways, in order to try to come up with an example of (broadly) three different approaches and you can make up your own mind.

The "meat" of the sample code is in the code behind on three buttons;

- `_button` makes use of continuations. (result is quite nested, even for this simple scenario.)
- `_button2` uses a dedicated background task and "invokes" UI update code.
- `_button3` uses the new async and await syntax.

I prototyped the code in  [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), so you should be able to cut and paste straight into Linqpad and it will run. If you want to compile/run the code from visual studio then you will need to replace the `Console.WriteLine's` with `Log4net` or `nlog` or similar to see the thread ID outputs.

I've sprinkled `DumpThread(..)'s` in key points in the code so that you can view the Current Thread's ID at various points in the code to see when (or if) the thread changes. Clicking `button3` for example produces the output shown below;

*clicking each of the three buttons produces the following output*

```
Main UI thread id : (19)
Form initialisation thread id : (19)

Nested Tasks + Delay && ContinueWith
---------------
Code behind outter thread id : (19)
continuation 1 thread id : (19)
continuation 2 thread id : (19)
continuation 3 thread id : (19)
continuation 4 thread id : (19)

bground monitor Task + final ContinueWith
---------------
code behind thread thread id : (19)
monitoring thread thread id : (4)
Invoker 1 thread id : (19)
Invoker 2 thread id : (19)
Invoker 3 thread id : (19)
Invoker 4 thread id : (19)

async && await (.net 4.5)
---------------
codebehind thread id : (19)
async step 1 thread id : (19)
async step 2 thread id : (19)
async step 3 thread id : (19)
async step 4 thread id : (19)
```

*Below is the code for a minimal winforms app with 3 buttons;*

```
    void Main()
{
        DumpThread("Main UI");
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public static void DumpThread(string msg) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(msg + " thread id : ({0})",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    }

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Label[] _lights = Enumerable.Range(1,4).Select (i => new Label() { Left = 100 + ((i-1) *25), Top = 90, Text=i.ToString(), BackColor = Color.Green, Width=20, Visible = true }).ToArray();
        private Label _threadLabel = new Label() { Left = 20, Top = 90, Text="Steps", Width = 50 };
        private TextBox _textbox = new TextBox() { Left = 100,  Top = 120, Text = "blah blah" };    
        private Label _label = new Label() { Left = 20, Top = 120, Text="Label" };
        private Button _button = new Button() { Left = 20, Top = 150, Width = 250,  Text = "Nested Tasks + Delay && ContinueWith" };
        private Button _button2 = new Button() { Left = 20, Top = 180, Width = 250,  Text = "bground monitor Task + final ContinueWith" };
        private Button _button3 = new Button() { Left = 20, Top = 210, Width = 250,  Text = "async && await (.net 4.5)" };      

        public Form1()
        {
            InitialiseControls();
            DumpThread("Form initialisation");

            // Task & ContinueWith
            // ********************
            // very nested continuations are hard to test or debug in more complex scenarios, 
            // considering the code below is a super simple contrived example and it's already not easy to read!
            _button.Click+= delegate 
            { 
                Heading(_button.Text);          
                DumpThread("Code behind outter");
                    Buttons(Enabled:false);
                    // simulate long running task followed by UI update
                    Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(ant0 => 
                    { 
                        DumpThread("continuation 1");
                        _lights[0].Visible = true; 
                        Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith( ant1 => 
                        {
                            DumpThread("continuation 2");
                            _lights[1].Visible = true; 
                            Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith( ant2 => 
                            {
                                DumpThread("continuation 3");
                                _lights[2].Visible = true; 
                                Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith( ant3 => 
                                {
                                    DumpThread("continuation 4");                               
                                    _lights[3].Visible = true; 
                                        Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith( ant4 => 
                                        {
                                            foreach(var light in _lights) light.Visible = false;
                                            Buttons(Enabled:true);
                                        },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                                },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                            },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                        },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                    },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());       
            };

            // ignoring the fact that we could simply foreach(var light in _lights) 
            // done this way in order to help us compare "appending" different blocks of code vs ContinueWith


            // bground Task && no continue with's
            // **********************************
            // traditional means of keeping UI responsive, create a background thread, ensure updates run on control creator's thread
            _button2.Click+= delegate 
            {
                Heading(_button2.Text);
                DumpThread("code behind thread");
                Buttons(Enabled:false);
                Task.Run(()=> {
                    DumpThread("monitoring thread");
                    Thread.Sleep(500); 
                    InvokeOnUIThread(_lights[0],l=> { l.Visible = true; DumpThread("Invoker 1");} );
                    Thread.Sleep(500); 
                    InvokeOnUIThread(_lights[1],l=> { l.Visible = true; DumpThread("Invoker 2");} );
                    Thread.Sleep(500); 
                    InvokeOnUIThread(_lights[2],l=> { l.Visible = true; DumpThread("Invoker 3");} );
                    Thread.Sleep(500); 
                    InvokeOnUIThread(_lights[3],l=> { l.Visible = true; DumpThread("Invoker 4");} );
                    Thread.Sleep(500); 
                    InvokeOnUIThread(_lights[3],l=> { 
                        Buttons(Enabled:true);
                        foreach(Label light in _lights) light.Visible = false;
                    } );
                    // finally
                });
            };          

            _button3.Click+=async delegate 
            {
                Heading(_button3.Text);
                DumpThread("codebehind");
                Buttons(Enabled:false);

                DumpThread("async step 1"); 
                _lights[0].Visible = true; 
                await Task.Delay(500);

                DumpThread("async step 2"); 
                _lights[1].Visible = true; 
                await Task.Delay(500);

                DumpThread("async step 3");
                _lights[2].Visible = true; 
                await Task.Delay(500);

                DumpThread("async step 4"); 
                _lights[3].Visible = true; 
                await Task.Delay(500);

                Buttons(Enabled:true);
                foreach(Label light in _lights) light.Visible = false;              
            };

        }       

        // allow us to invoke a method on the control's UI threads (the thread that created the control)
        private delegate void Invoker(Control control);
        private void InvokeOnUIThread(Control control, Action<Control> action)
        {
            if (!this.InvokeRequired) action(control);
            control.Invoke(new Invoker(action),control);
        }

        private void Buttons(bool Enabled) {
            _button.Enabled = Enabled;
            _button2.Enabled = Enabled;
            _button3.Enabled = Enabled;
        }

        void InitialiseControls()
        {
            //this.SuspendLayout();
            Controls.AddRange(_lights);
            Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {_threadLabel, _button, _textbox, _label,_button2, _button3 });         
            foreach(var l in _lights) l.Visible = false;
            //this.ResumeLayout();
        }   

        private void Heading(string heading) {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(heading);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------");
        }

    }
```

Clicking each button simulates 4 long running tasks that execute one after each other. Between each task, the UI is updated to reflect progress by hiding or showing one of 4 green label controls. The code above includes three different approaches to doing this without blocking or freezing the UI. I've found playing with a simple one page winforms app useful while trying out different async and threading code.

cheers, A

Comment: I've dropped the same code into a [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/goblinfactory/8166738) (The code is unfortunately a tad long & wide to easily read in SO, my bad.)

Comment: FYI, `async` and `await` are available on .NET 4.0 as well, if you install the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package. Also, "the cost of quite a bit of testability and readability" and "code that is tricky to read, test and maintain" are exactly the reasons `async` was invented in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

One of cases where `ContinueWith` is valuable is when continuation is applied to an aggregate `Task`, such as obtained via `Task.WhenAll`.

[image: Task combination diagram]

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task> ();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    tasks.Add (Task.Run (() => LongRunningOperation ()));
Task superTask = Task.WhenAll (tasks);
Task jobDone = superTask.ContinueWith (
    prevTask => MessageBox.Show ("Your operation is complete"));
return jobDone;
```

This gets particularly useful if your Tasks are computing partial results, which you then gather to form a final result:

```
List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>> ();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    tasks.Add (Task.Run (() => LongRunningComputation ()));
Task<int[]> allCompleted = Task.WhenAll (tasks);
Task jobDone = allCompleted.ContinueWith (
    aggregateTask => MessageBox.Show ("And the result is: " + aggregateTask.Result.Sum ()));
return jobDone;
```

Comment: The last example can be solved easier with async\await I think:
static async Task test()
{
List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => LongRunningComputation()));
var allCompleted = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
MessageBox.Show("And the result is: " + allCompleted.Sum());
}

Answer (score 0):

This answer lies within how long your tasks take to execute. As explained in [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454) by Jeffrey Richter (I highly recommend this book), if your task takes more than about a 5th of a second to execute, the windows operating system will have to [context switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In high throughput environments, context switching is considered an expensive operation.

If all of your methods execute within ~200 ms, separating your you method calls into individual tasks may be superfluous. Unless, of course, you need some of the task scheduling options as mentioned in another post.

[http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-C-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682105(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for this, will see if I can write a short spike to grok the context switching benefits and costs... although I think that this might just be "one" usage scenario, not **"the"** usage scenario. Either way, understanding at least one usage scenario is a start.

Comment: I don't think this is it either. Here's my reasoning, happy to be wrong. Let's assume you have 4 background "tasks", and 3 are quick a, b, and c, and (d) is super slow, so you want to mark (d) as long running. (Ignoring for the moment that LongRunning is the default). Marking a,b,c and quick, and d as long running is no different to appending a,b,c and d together (without `.ContinueWith`), and starting the background task running with a Task.Run() marking the whole snippet as long running? When it comes to executing the code, a, b and c are executed in a heartbeat and none's the wiser?

Comment: Do not get hung up on "long running". LongRunning is only a hint to the TaskScheduler. I believe that the default task scheduler ignores it, but I could be wrong. Either way, if all your code executes within a single CPU time slice, no context switching takes place. However, long-running or not, if your code takes more than can be executed in a single CPU time slice, the operating systems will swap it out with another thread for several ticks.

Comment: Again, read that book. It explains this issue at great length.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, however, wouldn't `QueueUserWorkItem` as recommended in this article [(Choosing Between the Task Parallel Library and the ThreadPool)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/10/06/9903475.aspx)  be more appropriate way of queuing long running tasks? If, on the otherhand the tasks are not long running, then we're back to square one, and my suggestion of simply 'appending' the code into a big block is cleaner?

Comment: The default task scheduler uses the ThreadPool's QueueUserWorkItem. Read Richter's book. It explains everything in the level of detail that you are looking for.

Comment: We've just been discussing this very issue in the answer above this one, and it would be very helpful if you could please provide an online reference to support your statement? (not a book) All I can find online after @I3arnon asked me for a reference when I said something similar is [this MSDN documentation that states 'The default scheduler for Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the .NET Framework ThreadPool to queue and execute work.'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am not following. When you see the sentence: "the default scheduler for Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the .NET Framework ThreadPool to queue and execute work," what does that mean to you?

Comment: Firstly, it says to me this is easily very confusing ;-D Secondly, while the article does clarify which Scheduler is used, it doesn't mention `QueueUserWorkItem` as a default. The program has to call it. It does have this sentence **"the ThreadPool uses the information ... to efficiently support the fine-grained parallelism (short-lived units of work)"** though. Meaning I don't think default scheduler in .Net 4.5 (`ThreadPool`) uses long running defaults with `Task.Run(...)` or `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`, which is why I was asking for an online reference so that I see if I can work this out?

Comment: Please bear with me as I am trying to help, but I do not think I got the answer to my last question. Let me re-ask only the relevant part of the question. What does it mean to you when you see the phrase "uses the .NET framework ThreadPool to queue and execute work." From where I am coming from, it says that it is going to call one of the variations of the QueueUserWork methods on ThreadPool. If we can get on the same page here, perhaps we can move on to finding common ground on the definition of "long running".

Comment: Upvoted for the valuable nugget of information.  Although... what the equivalent of 200ms of 2013's time in 2019?   Also @snowcode I feel your pain.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/583945/improve-asynchronous-programming-model.html

Answer (score -1):

been a long time since I asked this question, and async is now popular and well known in both C# and javascript, and in both languages the modern answer to this question is now simply **"It's a matter of personal preference."**
:D
i.e. no difference any more, totally a matter of preference.